# Grey (not black) shadow box?

Tags: boxes, shadows

I would like to change the default color of a shadowbox to grey. How to do that with no problem of equation "style"/"management" inside the shadowbox ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possibility defining commands `\Cshadowbox` and `\@Cshadowbox` analogously to `\shadowbox` and `\@shadowbox` as implemented in `fancybox.sty`; the color can be changed using `ShadowColor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\definecolor{ShadowColor}{RGB}{30,150,190}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Cshadowbox{\VerbBox\@Cshadowbox}
\def\@Cshadowbox#1{%
  \setbox\@fancybox\hbox{\fbox{#1}}%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \dimen@=\shadowsize
    \advance\dimen@ .5\fboxrule
    \hbox{\copy\@fancybox\kern.5\fboxrule\lower\shadowsize\hbox{%
      \color{ShadowColor}\vrule \@height\ht\@fancybox \@depth\dp\@fancybox \@width\dimen@}}%
    \vskip\dimexpr-\dimen@+0.5\fboxrule\relax
    \moveright\shadowsize\vbox{%
      \color{ShadowColor}\hrule \@width\wd\@fancybox \@height\dimen@}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\shadowbox{$a=b$}

\Cshadowbox{$a=b$}

\definecolor{ShadowColor}{RGB}{90,0,20}

\Cshadowbox{$a=b$}

\colorlet{ShadowColor}{gray}

\Cshadowbox{$a=b$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this possible to change the rule color for `\ovalbox`? Please suggest...