# Coloured shadowed boxes around equations

Tags: formatting, equations, color, boxes, shadows

When I want to highlight some important result, I traditionnally put my equations in boxes:

```
\begin{equation}
boxed{\Delta = b^2-4ac}
\end{equation}
```

I would like to have a more fancy thing:

- to be able to set the thickness and the color of the line of the box
- to be able to add a coloured shadow under this box

to obtain this kind of result:

[image]

I asked the same kind of question a while ago (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65583/grey-not-black-shadow-box)) but the answer does not work for equations.

How to do that?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13681/highlight-an-equation-within-an-align-environment?rq=1

Comment: I read your question again and saw that you want **coloured** shadows. Now, I extended my answer with examples for such **coloured** shadows.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here are some additions using `tcolorbox`. You can use a macro `\tcbhighmath` which is designed for such a task. The style can be varied also by options given to this macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins,theorems]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
  colframe=red,colback=white,arc=0pt,boxrule=1pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath[drop fuzzy shadow]{\Delta = b^2 - 4ac}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath[boxrule=2pt,drop fuzzy shadow=blue]{E = m\cdot c^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath[boxrule=0.4pt,colframe=blue,drop fuzzy shadow=red]{a^2 + b^2} =
\tcbhighmath[arc=4pt,drop fuzzy shadow=green]{c^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath[boxrule=2pt,arc=1pt,colback=blue!10!white,colframe=blue,
  drop fuzzy shadow=red]{ \ln|x| = \int\limits_1^x t~dt }
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath[fuzzy halo=1mm with blue!50!white,arc=2pt,
  boxrule=0pt,frame hidden]{ \ln|x| = \int\limits_1^x t~dt }
\end{equation}

\tcbset{myinner/.style={no shadow,shrink tight,extrude by=1mm,colframe=blue,
  boxrule=0.4pt,frame style={opacity=0.25},interior style={opacity=0.5}}}
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath[drop fuzzy shadow=red!50!yellow,colback=red!20!white]{
  \tcbhighmath[myinner]{\Delta} =
  \tcbhighmath[myinner]{b^2 - 4ac}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I can't say I know all the ins and outs of `tcolorbox`, but this demonstrates that it works with equation material.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
Testing
\begin{equation}
\tcbox[nobeforeafter]{\( \Delta = b^2 - 4ac \)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the intended purpose I would recommend the `\tcbhighmath` macro from `tcolorbox` instead of `\tcbox`. Nevertheless, you could achieve the same with `\tcbox` and additional options :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I defer to your expertise on `tcolorbox`.  Thanks for the tip, which will aid me and the readers of this.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Is there any way to get rid of the rounded corners? I prefer sharp corners.

Comment: @far.westerner Best to ask Thomas Sturm, who provided the other answer and who wrote the `tcolorbox` package.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Tcolorbox manual, they provide custom `ams equation` environments inside the `tcolorbox` so you don't even have to make an `equation` environment:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation, colback=yellow, colframe=red]
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty
\end{tcolorbox}
```

They also provide environments like `ams align` (just replace with this option in the above), which is very handy.

Comment: the solution provided by https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206944/tcolorbox-equation-and-fleqn-not-vertically-centered is `\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align]` is nicer