# tcolorbox equation and fleqn: not vertically centered

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

Using `tcolorbox` with `ams equation,` there is sometimes additional leading space before the equation comes:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation]
    A = B
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{document}
```

Versus

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation]
    A = B
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{document}
```

How can I remove it or have the equation centered vertically? The option `fleqn` seems to be significant here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I took the liberty to slightly improve the tags and the formatting of your question, I hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 4):

```
 \documentclass[fleqn]{article}
 \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align]
    A = B
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what a shame ... we go to so much effort to try to tell people that using `align` for single-line displays is not the right thing to do.  i think i'll try to persuade the author of `tcolorbox` that this is a bug.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've added an answer with a patch for the `fleqn` case. I'm not sure if the different space settings by the `amsmath` package are deliberately done ... (?)

Answer (score 4):

The `amsmath` package seems to add extra vertical space for an `equation` only *with* the `fleqn` option. I'm not sure if that's a bug or a feature, but currently `tcolorbox` is not aware of the different space settings with or without `fleqn`.

The following patch seems to do the trick:

```
\makeatletter
\if@fleqn
\tcbset{%
  ams equation upper/.style={before upper=\tcb@hack@amsmath\equation,after upper=\endequation},%
  ams equation lower/.style={before lower=\tcb@hack@amsmath\equation,after lower=\endequation},%
  ams equation* upper/.style={before upper=\tcb@hack@amsmath\csname equation*\endcsname,after upper=\endequation},%
  ams equation* lower/.style={before lower=\tcb@hack@amsmath\csname equation*\endcsname,after lower=\endequation}%
}
\fi
\makeatother
```

All together, this gives:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\if@fleqn
\tcbset{%
  ams equation upper/.style={before upper=\tcb@hack@amsmath\equation,after upper=\endequation},%
  ams equation lower/.style={before lower=\tcb@hack@amsmath\equation,after lower=\endequation},%
  ams equation* upper/.style={before upper=\tcb@hack@amsmath\csname equation*\endcsname,after upper=\endequation},%
  ams equation* lower/.style={before lower=\tcb@hack@amsmath\csname equation*\endcsname,after lower=\endequation}%
}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
abc
\begin{equation}
    A = B
\end{equation}
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation]
    A = B
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align]
    A = B
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

This code works with and without `fleqn`.

Comment: thanks very much.  i will look into the anomaly you report; without investigation, i think it may well have to do with the assumption that for use with ams document classes, the equation number is assumed to be on the left, not the right.  i'll get back to you, off-line.