# Extra vertical space in tcolorbox equation

Tags: math-mode, tcolorbox

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation*]
        x = y
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know how to make the equation vertically centered in the tcolorbox.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206944/tcolorbox-equation-and-fleqn-not-vertically-centered?rq=1