# Help Recreating Equation Format

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, color, tcolorbox

I am writting my thesis and really like to be able to make some equations like the one shown in the picture but don't know how. Your help is really appreciated.

[image: https://towardsdatascience.com/particle-swarm-optimization-visually-explained-46289eeb2e14e]

Image taken from : https://towardsdatascience.com/particle-swarm-optimization-visually-explained-46289eeb2e14

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide a minimal working example demonstrating what you *can* do? This should start with `\documentclass{}` and end `\end{document}`. You can look at `tikzmarks`, for example, for the shading.

Comment: You can also look at `tcolorbox`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122945/coloured-shadowed-boxes-around-equations

Comment: Have a look at the https://ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz package

Comment: (and please don't set whole words in mah mode, e.g. this messes up the kerning and spaces are missing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my attempt with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={minimum height=2cm,rounded corners=3mm,anchor=base,
label={[anchor=south]south:{\scriptsize\bfseries\textsf{#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
P_i^{t+1} &= P_i^t+V_i^{t+1}\\
V_i^{t+1} &=
\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[fill=gray!20,mystyle=Inertia\strut] (t1)
    {$w V_i^t$}} + 
\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[fill=magenta!20,mystyle=Cognitive(Personal)] (t2)
    {$c_1 r_1\left(P_{best(i)}^t - P_i^t\right)$}} + 
\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[fill=teal!20,mystyle=Social(Global)] (t3)
    {$c_2 r_2\left(P_{bestglobal}^t-P_i^t\right)$}}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, perfect! Let me say thank you very much!

Comment: @Andrey L. For vertical alignment of labels, I suggest putting `\strut`, not only for Inertia but in the command after `\textsf{#1}`

Comment: @pascal974, thanks, that's a good point.